# input vectors outside of main function c++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I am trying to get an input to a matrix by placing the whole thing as in a function outside of main (), as follows:

```
    void input_matrix(int row, int col){
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
  
  for (int m=0; m<row; m++){
    for (int n=0; n<col; n++){
      std::cin >> matrix[m][n];
    }
  }
  return matrix;
}
```

somehow the compiler doesn't like me inputing the matrix here, any solutions?

Comment: You gotta change the return type of the function from `void` to `vector<vector<int> >`

Comment: Yes, please post the compiler's error message verbatim, as text.  Identify in your posted code, which statement the compiler is referring to.

Comment: `matrix` is empty. `matrix[m][n]` is an error. You need to first resize `matrix` and each subvector, or use `push_back`/`emplace_back`.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(m, std::vector<int>(n));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

1. The return type of the function `input_matrix()` is void which needs to be changed to `vector<vector<int> >`
2. Initialize the `matrix` with proper space.

The corrected code would look something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > input_matrix(int row, int col){
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix(row, std::vector<int>(col));
  
    for (int m=0; m<row; m++){
        for (int n=0; n<col; n++){
            std::cin >> matrix[m][n];
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate! I'm somewhat new to coding, that's why it wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: @Halikon If it helped you. You can consider accepting the answer :)